# Criar função função de conversão hexadecimal e octal em python

Tags: python, programação-funcional

Boa noite, estou tentando fazer duas funções uma para converter numeros hexadecimais em decimais e uma para converter numeros octais em decimais, este é o meu codigo:

```
def hexadecimalparadecimal(n):
    decimal = 0
    n = str(n)
    n = n[::-1]
    tam = len(n)
    num = list("0123456789ABCDEF")
    for i in range(tam):
        if n[i] == '1':
            decimal = decimal + 16**i
            print('EM DECIMAL: {}'.format (decimal))
    return decimal
```

O problema que a conversão está errada, quando eu comparo a string com um 1 esta tudo bem, mais ainda não consegui usar todos os valores, tentei por os valores em uma lista e comparar mas deu erro, além disso tentei fazer A = 10, B = 11 mais ainda não consegui digitar a letra recebendo os seus valores, no octal não tenho esse problema com letras mas ainda não consegui fazer a soma de todos valores, usar os numeros da lista, alguém sabe como usar a lista neste caso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fala Danilo, entendi, veja se este código abaixo que maneiro, ele esta no tópico em que te falei anteriormente.

```
def todec2(hexa):
    x = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 
         'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
    hexalista = list(hexa) #passa para lista 
    resultado = 0
    for pos, digit in enumerate(hexalista[-1::-1]): 
        posicao = x.index(digit)
        resultado = (int(posicao) * (16**pos)) + resultado
    return(resultado)
```

É o seguinte,no laço `for` a função `enumerate` indexa o numero passado, que ja era uma lista, tornando por exemplo o hexadecimal '2E' de:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em :
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então, agora tenho posição(`pos`) e o digito(`digit`) correspondente aquela posição, onde para valores acima de 9, serão atribuidos os valores 11,12,13... devido ao index numérico, o que mata sua questão de atribuir valores as letras.

Desta forma atribuimos a variavel `posicao` o index do digito(que posição ele esta na lista) e então partimos para a conta.

A variavel `resultado` então recebe as operações onde a `posicao` multiplica a base 16 a variavel `pos` lembrando que esta é o iterador do loop e começa em 0, no loop seguinte `pos` será 1 e assim por diante.

O "truque" para tal regularidade é a ordenção feita na lista com `[-1::-1]` que inverte a lista e itera primeiramente o digito menos significativo, que na regra da conversão, recebe 16^0, posteriormente os digitos mais significativos recebem 16^1,16^2, e assim por diante.

Um exemplo para ilustrar os valores, vamos supor que desejo converter '2E'(16), cujo resultado é 46(10), repare nos valores que as variaveis comentadas acima tomam.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Outro exemplo de bruxaria pythoniana é o código abaixo, que não consegui entender ainda haha, abraço.

```
def hexToDec(hexi):
result = 0;
for ch in hexi:
if 'A' <= ch <= 'F':
  result = result * 16 + ord(ch) - ord('A') + 10
else:
  result = result * 16 + ord(ch) - ord('0')
return result;
```

[python hex to decimal using for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21400082/python-hex-to-decimal-using-for-loop)

Answer (score 2):

Boa tarde campeão, tudo bem?

Você deseja realmente fazer desta forma, digamos "na unha" ? Pois o python ja tem funções implementadas para tal tarefa.

Geralmente se faz como mostrado abaixo, de uma forma mais pythonica.

**Hex para dec**

```
def hexadecimalparadecimal(numero):
    convertido = int(numero,16)
    return convertido
```

**Oct para dec**

```
def octalparadecimal(numero2):
    convertido2 = int(numero2,8)
    return convertido2
```

É só chamar a função e dar um valor entre aspas, exemplo :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Caso você deseje códigos mais na "unha" encontrei alguns sobre octal para decimal neste topico do stack em inglês : [Octal>Decimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35450560/how-to-use-python-to-convert-an-octal-to-a-decimal)

Abraço.

Claudio.

Comment: Sim, no caso seria na unha sem funçoes nativas.